# How do I have to read the following statement?

Tags: c++, c

I liked to refresh my C++ skills and tried to programm a little Object, so I came about this expression:

```
int (*const vectors)[2];
```

How do I read it? I know that it is declaring a constant pointer pointing to a two dimensional int array.

Thank you!

Comment: If you know what it means, seems to me you read it correctly. So I don't understand what you are asking about. Would you clarify, please?

Comment: [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*const+vectors%29%5B2%5D)

Comment: The problem is, how I handle the array brackets. The normal way is from the left to the right, but these brackets blow up my thought. @GSerg Thanks.

Comment: It's a pointer to *one* array with two integers. You can't tell from the type whether a pointer points to an array element or not – in this case, you can only hope that the name being plural is correct.

Comment: [chist.html](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) - Embryonic C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the spiral rule to parse `int (*const vectors)[2];`:

- start from the identifier `vectors`
- handle the unary operators on its right, from left to right, there are none before the ')`.
- handle the qualifiers and unary operators on its left, from right to left:

  - `const` means `vectors` is constant, you cannot modify its value.
  - `*` means pointer: *`vector` is a constant pointer*
- skip the parentheses on both sides and start again:

  - `[2]` means *array of 2*. *`vector` is a constant pointer to one or more arrays of 2*
  - finally: `int` gives the inner element type.

`vector` is a constant pointer to one or more arrays of 2 `int`.

Hence `vector` can be made to point to an array of arrays of 2 `int`. For example you can use `vector` to manipulate a 2D matrix this way:

```
// allocate a 2D identity matrix:
int (*const vectors)[2] = malloc(sizeof(int[2][2]);
vectors[0][0] = vectors[1][1] = 1;
vectors[1][0] = vectors[0][1] = 0;
```

Note however that `vectors` must be initialized, not assigned because it is defined as `const`. If you intend for `vectors` to point to a 2D matrix that should not be modified, for example as a function argument, the declaration should be:

```
void print_matrix(const int (*vectors)[2]);
```

Or

```
void print_matrix(int const (*vectors)[2]);
```

Finally, there are subtile differences for the meaning of `const` in C and C++, but the parsing method describe above applies to both languages.

Answer (score 0):

In a declaration, both prefix `*` and postfix `[]` are operators that modify an identifier (or declarator).

The thing is that `[]` has higher precedence than `*`, so if you left the parens out, you would declare `vectors` as an array size 2 of `int * const`.

The parens are needed to make `vectors` a const pointer to `int [2]`.